# How to get post published date from the wp api in the same format of "get_the_date( )" in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have page that contain:
1. Section that show the **last post** and **show his date creation** by  On format :**"March 10, 2020"**

.2  Form That on click add post new post by the wp-api

Then from the response, I like to update the section with the last date creation but I got in a different format.

The date from the json is in the format   **'2020-03-10T11:53:10'** 
Not like 
The format from the  On format :**"March 10, 2020"**

How to get it or format it the same one as `get_the_date();`

Answer (score 1):

Use the PHP date format function

```
$date = new Date("F d, Y", strtotime($yourDateString));
```

Check this reference for other format options

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php